# JAVA: Infinite loop issue

Tags: java

I'm completely new to Java and I have made this program for an assignment in my intermediate class. It is supposed to prompt users for information, and then display it in a table. The program works just as intended except when prompted to answer "y or n", if answered anything besides "y" it loops infinitely. 
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class InterestCalculator
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

      double startingBalance;
      double interestRate;
      double endingBalance;
      double interestEarned;
      char yesOrNo;
      int temp;
      int numberOfQuarters;


      while(true)
      {
          System.out.println("Enter number of quarters from 1 to 10");
          numberOfQuarters = userInput.nextInt();
          if (numberOfQuarters > 0 && numberOfQuarters <=10)
          {
              break;
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("Number of quarters must be between 1 and 10 inclusive");
          }
      }

      while(true)
      {
          System.out.println("Enter the beginning principal balance greater than zero");
          startingBalance = userInput.nextDouble();
          if (startingBalance > 0)
          {
              break;
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("Beginning balance must be greater than zero");
          }
      }


      while(true)
      {
          System.out.println("Enter the interest rate percentage without the percent sign, greater than 0 percent and less than/equal to 20%"
            );
          interestRate = userInput.nextDouble();
          if (interestRate > 0 && interestRate <= 20)
          {
              break;
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("Interest rate must be between 1 and 20 inclusive");
          }
      }

      System.out.println("You entered a principal balance of $" + startingBalance + " for " + numberOfQuarters + " quarters at " + interestRate + "% interest.");
      System.out.println("Is this correct? (y/n)");
      yesOrNo = userInput.next().charAt(0);

      while(true)
      {   
         if (yesOrNo == 'y' || yesOrNo == 'Y')
         {
            break;            
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Please provide the information again");
         }
      }

      System.out.println("Quarter       Beginning       Interest       Ending");
      System.out.println("Number        Balance         Earned         Balance");
      //here is where I am doing my calculations 
      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuarters; ++i)
      {     
         interestEarned = (startingBalance * (interestRate / 100) * (0.25) );
         endingBalance = startingBalance + interestEarned;

         System.out.printf((i+1) + "%20.2f %14.2f %15.2f \n", startingBalance, interestEarned, endingBalance);



      }
   }
}
```

I am really a noob so I'm sorry for how messy this might be and if its something minor that I should know.

Thank you very much.

Here is the portion specifically:

```
   System.out.println("You entered a principal balance of $" + startingBalance + " for " + numberOfQuarters + " quarters at " + interestRate + "% interest.");
          System.out.println("Is this correct? (y/n)");
          yesOrNo = userInput.next().charAt(0);

          while(true)
          {   
             if (yesOrNo == 'y' || yesOrNo == 'Y')
             {
                break;            
             }
             else
             {
                System.out.println("Please provide the information again");
             }
          }
```

Comment: The value of `i` does not figure into the calculation at all, so the result is exactly the same on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Highlighting the portion of the code you assume is wrong could help as well.

Comment: you should add break in the else clouse

Comment: @jh365 Take care when posting to Stack Overflow. Write a title that that states the core issue, not "please help me". Reduce your example code the bare minimum to demonstrate your problem. And search Stack Overdlow before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're really trying to achieve, but i think you'r missing a variable. You're always making you calculations based on your `startingBalance`, and you never change its value, so you're always getting the same values.

See if this helps.

```
    double currentBalance = startingBalance;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuarters; ++i) {
        interestEarned = (currentBalance * (interestRate / 100) * (0.25));
        endingBalance = currentBalance + interestEarned;

        System.out.printf((i + 1) + "%20.2f %14.2f %15.2f \n", currentBalance, interestEarned, endingBalance);

        currentBalance = endingBalance;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, but when I put it in my code and try to run it, it says "InterestCalculator.java:84: error: cannot find symbol"

Comment: And what do you have in line 84? replace your last `for loop` by the code i posted :)

Comment: it works! thank you so much! You have saved my life

Answer (score 1):

In the above mentioned code, the starting balance changes for every quarter rather than one. hence the starting balance must be the ending balance of the previous quarter.
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
 class InterestCalculator
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

         Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        double startingBalance;
            double interestRate;
        double endingBalance;
         double interestEarned;
         char yesOrNo;
        int temp;
         int numberOfQuarters;


         while(true)
         {
                System.out.println("Enter number of quarters from 1 to 10");
             numberOfQuarters = userInput.nextInt();
                if (numberOfQuarters > 0 && numberOfQuarters <=10)
                {
                     break;
                }
                else
                {
                     System.out.println("Number of quarters must be between 1 and 10 inclusive");
                }
        }

         while(true)
        {
             System.out.println("Enter the beginning principal balance greater than zero");
             startingBalance = userInput.nextDouble();
                if (startingBalance > 0)
             {
                     break;
             }
             else
                {
                    System.out.println("Beginning balance must be greater than zero");
             }  
        }


         while(true)
         {
                System.out.println("Enter the interest rate percentage without the percent sign, greater than 0 percent and less than/equal to 20%"
             );
             interestRate = userInput.nextDouble();
            if (interestRate > 0 && interestRate <= 20)
                {
                 break;
             }
             else
                {
                     System.out.println("Interest rate must be between 1 and 20 inclusive");
             }
        }

        System.out.println("You entered a principal balance of $" + startingBalance + " for " + numberOfQuarters + " quarters at " + interestRate + "% interest.");
        System.out.println("Is this correct? (y/n)");
        yesOrNo = userInput.next().charAt(0);

        while(true)
        {   
             if (yesOrNo == 'y' || yesOrNo == 'Y')
            {
                    break;            
            }
            else
            {
                    System.out.println("Please provide the information again");
            }
        }

         System.out.println("Quarter       Beginning       Interest       Ending");
        System.out.println("Number        Balance         Earned         Balance");

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuarters; ++i)
        {     
            interestEarned = (startingBalance * (interestRate / 100) * (0.25) );
            endingBalance = startingBalance + interestEarned;

            System.out.printf((i+1) + "%20.2f %14.2f %15.2f \n", startingBalance, interestEarned, endingBalance);
        startingBalance=endingBalance;


        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some endless loop. To solve that each else clouse you have should include a break in the last line so it will print only 1 message to the console. Here is one example how to do it:

```
    while(true)
    {
        if (yesOrNo == 'y' || yesOrNo == 'Y')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please provide the information again");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Replace the following line:

```
System.out.println("Enter the interest rate percentage without the percent sign, greater than 0 percent and less than/equal to 20%");
```

with the line:

```
System.out.println("Enter the interest rate percentage without the percent sign, greater than 0 percent and less than/equal to " + startingBalance/numberOfQuarters );
```

Mistakenly you hard coded the 20% into the printing line.

Comment: Hi the 20% was intended, but yeah I need to fix this endless loop. When I run it, and the user is asked if the info is correct, and they enter "n" or no, it asks them endlessly "Please enter the correct info" endlessly. Hmmm how exactly can I fix this.

Comment: I edited my answer and inserted an example to handle the endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Along with minor mistakes like hard-coded values, you have serious flaws:

1. Following code will be infinite loop for values other than 'Y' or 'y',

*Infinite Loop Section:*

```
while (true) {
    if (yesOrNo == 'y' || yesOrNo == 'Y') {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please provide the information again");
    }
}
```

2. As mentioned by `djointster`, you have not made the proper initialization for calculations, so sending a zero (`0`) will bring `interestEarned` to zero.

Comment: I'm currently trying to fix this infinite loop part, the hard coded values like the 20% are intended. Sorry I'm a huge noob to java. Any tips on the infinite loop? I'm doing searches and reading my book but no luck :(